# How to get the next element that contains text with a specific value using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have the following XML:

```
<w:r w:rsidR="00AB3D3B">
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">His sister </w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:ins w:author="Chell" w:date="2016-10-02T11:19:00Z" w:id="5">
        <w:r w:rsidR="00AB3D3B">
            <w:t>P</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:ins>
    <w:bookmarkStart w:id="6" w:name="_GoBack"/>
    <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="6"/>
    <w:del w:author="Chell" w:date="2016-10-02T11:19:00Z" w:id="7">
        <w:r w:rsidDel="00AB3D3B" w:rsidR="00AB3D3B">
            <w:delText>p</w:delText>
        </w:r>
    </w:del>
    <w:r w:rsidR="00AB3D3B">
        <w:t>olley had a sharp eye for detail.</w:t>
    </w:r>
```

I select all of the inserted nodes:

```
 @insertions = @file.xpath("//w:ins")
```

The first element is:

```
<w:ins w:author="Chell" w:date="2016-10-02T11:19:00Z" w:id="5">
    <w:r w:rsidR="00AB3D3B">
        <w:t>P</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:ins>
```

I need to get the next element that contains the tag `<w:del>` and the text = "p".

I can't use `node.next_element` as that returns the bookmark element.

How can I do this with Nokogiri?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using XPath `following-sibling` axis for this task :

```
@file.xpath("//w:ins/following-sibling::w:del[. = 'p'][1]")
```

**brief explanation :**

- **`/following-sibling::w:del`** : find `w:del` element located after current `w:ins` ...
- **`[. = 'p'][1]`** : ... where inner text equals 'p', and then limit the result to 1. In other words, for each `w:ins`, return only the nearest `w:del` that match the criteria

Comment: Thanks har07 fantastic answer. I never saw that method following-sibling.  Great to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood the question, you are looking for the respective `w:del` element. You might want to just catch them both with `xpath`:

```
doc = %q|<w:r w:rsidR="00AB3D3B"> ... |
xml = Nokogiri::XML(doc)
ins, del, * = xml.xpath('//w:ins[@w:author="Chell"]//w:t|//w:del[@w_author="Chell"]//w:delText')
[ins, del]
#⇒ => [
#  [0] #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x32f0b2c name="w_t" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x32ef0ec "P">]>,
#  [1] #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x32f0b18 name="w_delText" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x32eea70 "p">]>
# ]
```

That way you’ll get the subsequent elements for `w:ins` and `w:del`.

Comment: This is also very helpful. I accepted har07 as it was more inline with that I was looking for.  Thanks Mudasobwa.